# Failed to install dependecies on ubuntu

Tags: ruby, linux, rubygems

I want to install HospitalRun on a Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS [HospitalRun Link][1]. I cloned the github and when I try the command `bundle install` I get the following error:

```
An error occurred while installing eventmachine (1.2.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install eventmachine -v '1.2.7' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  jekyll-archives was resolved to 2.2.1, which depends on
    jekyll was resolved to 3.9.1, which depends on
      em-websocket was resolved to 0.5.2, which depends on
        eventmachine
```

Can someone please help me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think there's probably more to this error message. Can you show us the rest?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing the ruby-dev package needed to compile the native extension for eventmache.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
```